# How to know if incorrect binary search algorithm always terminates without testing

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, proof, proof-of-correctness

Consider the following algorithm where target = 13 and array = [5,10,15,20,25] where N = length of array

```
lo = 1
hi = N
while lo < hi:
    mid = (lo+hi)//2
    if target >= array[mid]:
        lo = mid
    else:
        hi = mid
if array[lo] == target:
    return lo
return False
```

I know that the above algorithm doesn't terminate for the above case where array = [5,10,15,20,25] and target = 13. And so, we can conclude that the algorithm doesn't **always** terminate.

But say if I had array = [5,10,15,20,25] and target = 1, then the algorithm would terminate.

So, using inputs to determine whether an algorithm always terminates or not is not good because it is not a foolproof way of determining whether an algorithm **always** terminates or not.

And so my question is, is there a way I can prove that the above algorithm always terminates without using any inputs/cases?

Thank you for any suggestions and insights. Appreciate the help.

Comment: "Is there a way I can prove that the above algorithm always terminates without using any inputs/cases?" is a rather vague question. You just do the usual things when proving algorithms. Identify invariants, prove that each step preserves invariants, prove that the invariant leads to termination.

Comment: @RaymondChen So, are you saying I need to always use invariants to check whether an algorithm terminates or not? But for some simple algorithms, you don't need to use invariants. For simple algorithms, you can simply see that the algorithm always terminates by analyzing the while loop condition and the while loop body. For example if the while loop condition is index < 5 and index is incremented at each loop iteration, then we know for a fact that the loop will terminate when index >= 5. So, no need for any invariants. But it's not straightforward with the above algorithm in the post.

Comment: If all you care about is termination (and not correctness) you can often take shortcuts.

Comment: @RaymondChen Hence my question, which is about how to show whether the algorithm terminates or not. So, what shortcuts do you mean?

Comment: They are all case-by-case. In this case, you can try to prove that the number of elements in the range (lo..hi) always decreases at every iteration.

Comment: @RaymondChen You mean I have to use cases to show that the algorithm always/doesn't always terminate? But this can take a long time for certain algorithms because there are infinitely many possible cases for certain algorithms. And it's not practical to test all the cases.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "use cases". In this example, you would show that the range always shrinks by at least 1 per iteration. Since the initial range is finite, this sets an upper bound on the number of iterations. It's also true that not all algorithms have been proved to terminate. Collatz, for example, has yet to be proven to terminate.

Comment: @RaymondChen Right, so how can you show that the range always shrinks by at least 1 without using any sample inputs? As in, how can I generalize it? Because I can easily show that the range may/may not reduce with sample inputs but how I can generalize it with math?

Comment: You have to use logic.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah, that's what I am struggling with.

Comment: I think the reason you're struggling to prove that it always terminates is because it is impossible to prove that it always terminates, because the statement is false. You yourself found a counter-example.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah, I can provide sample inputs and show that it doesn't terminate; hence, showing that it doesn't always terminate but this is not a guaranteed way of showing it doesn't always terminate because there is a chance of always choosing sample inputs that makes the algorithm terminate even though there are inputs that makes it not terminate. And so, that's why I am looking for a way to show with logic/math that the algorithm doesn't always terminate.

Comment: Proving "X does not always happen" is the same as disproving "X always happens", which you can do by counter-example. In this case, proving "does not always terminate" is the same as disproving "always terminates", which can be done by showing a case where it doesn't terminate. Proving that something always terminates is harder, since you have to use logic, not counter-examples.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am trying to show that it doesn't always terminate without any inputs. If we don't know whether an algorithm always terminates or not, yes, we could plug in some inputs and see if terminates or not. But what if all my inputs show that the algorithm terminates even though in reality, the algorithm doesn't terminate for some cases? That's why I am trying to use logic and math to show that the algorithm doesn't always terminate because I could get unlucky when using inputs since there are infinitely many possible inputs.

Comment: It's strange that you aren't allowed to prove via counterexample. That is a perfectly legitimate technique for proving a negative. At any rate, you can use your counterexample to analyze the algorithm and discover where it breaks down, and then provide your analysis without reference to the counterexample.

Comment: @RaymondChen Looks to me like you two are talking circles around the fact that you usually *find* the counterexample by trying to *prove* termination and noticing a "gap" in the proof attempt. Like Yves' answer did when they found that `(hi - lo)\\2` *isn't* smaller than `hi - lo` if that's 1.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's often the case, but in this case the counterexample was already stumbled upon. But yes, you can often find the counterexample by trying to prove something and realizing that the proof isn't coming together. The thing that prevents it from coming together is your counterexample. (But that doesn't help OP, who for some reason isn't allowed to use a counterexample to disprove something.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I think you misunderstood the OP. That kinda is my point. Where did they say they're not allowed to use a counterexample? I only see them being worried about not finding one even though one exists. They seem to think the way to find a counterexample is to randomly try examples and hope to "stumble upon" a counterexample. And they're right that failing to find any that way that doesn't prove that there aren't any. Which is why I pointed out the attempt-to-prove way to find counterexamples.

Comment: @KellyBundy "I am trying to show that it doesn't always terminate without any inputs." The counter-example is a set of inputs that shows that it doesn't terminate, but they say that want to do it "without any inputs". (But yes, we agree if you can't get the proof to come together, the thing that you can't get to work could be your counter-example.)

Comment: @RaymondChen And I think you misinterpret that. Later in that same comment they say *"**That's why I am trying to use logic** and math to show that the algorithm doesn't always terminate because I **could get unlucky when using inputs** since there are infinitely many possible inputs"*. The reason they want to use "logic and math" is because they might just get "unlucky" with a set of non-counterexamples. That doesn't mean that they'd reject a counterexample or even aren't allowed to use one. They're just saying they want to be sure. Which they *are* if they do find a counterexample.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah. It wasn't "I am trying to show that it doesn't always terminate without any inputs." It was ""I am trying to show that it doesn't always terminate from first principles, without relying on the known counter-example." I was faked out because of an earlier statement about looking for shortcuts. The counter-example is the best shortcut!

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah, I think the misunderstanding started back there, with the word "case". You meant this *problem/algorithm*, while they interpreted it as *input* case.

Comment: @RaymondChen Apologies for any confusion. This is not a task that is set by anyone. I understand that I can use counter-examples to prove that the algorithm doesn't terminate; hence, doesn't always terminate. But I am looking for a way to show with logic/math that the algorithm doesn't always terminate without using any counter-examples because I could be unlucky and choose counter-examples that proves the algorithm terminates. There are answers in this post and so I just have to take time and try to understand it. Thanks for your time. And Kelly Bundy understood what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

In a binary search, if you want to make sure that the loop terminates, then you need to make sure that the range (`hi-lo`) shrinks with every iteration.  You also need to make sure that `lo` and `hi` are within the valid range (1-N in your case).

It starts with your test:

```
if target >= array[mid]:
```

If this test is false, then `mid` is *too high*.  If this test passes, though, then `mid` is not necessarily too low.  It might be the value you're looking for.   Knowing that, you can can handle the cases:

```
if target >= array[mid]:
    # answer is >= mid
    lo = mid
else:
    # answer is < mid
    hi = mid-1
```

So here you see the first problem fixed -- because you're using a "too high" test instead of a "too low" test, you get `hi = mid-1` -- a little bit unusual, but we can make it work.

So, now you know how the range is going to change.  Given `lo < hi` and `mid`, the two possible new ranges are `[lo,mid-1]` and `[mid,hi]`.  BOTH of these ranges must be smaller than `[lo,hi]` if you want the loop to terminate in all cases. so you require `mid-1 < hi`, which is the same as `mid <= hi`, and you require `mid > lo`, which is the same as `lo <= mid-1`.   Those ranges also need to be valid, so you require `lo <= mid-1` and `mid <= hi`, which happen to be the same as the above conditions.

With all of that together, you need: `lo <= mid-1 < mid <= hi`.  The way you currently calculate `mid` does NOT ensure this.  In order to make sure that `lo < mid`, you need to round UP, so you should set `mid` like this:

```
mid = (lo+hi+1)//2
```

Or even better, like this:

```
mid = lo + (hi+1-low)//2
```

That gives the same answer, but avoids overflowing integers in some languages.  It's a good habit.

With these changes, your binary search will work.

Comment: Do you guarantee that if target falls between array[mid-1] and array[mid], the algorithm is still valid ?

Comment: Yes.  We are searching for the position where the target has to be (there's a check at the end to see if it's actually there).  There are no positions between `mid-1` and `mid`, because positions are integers.

Comment: There can be target values there. Is it sure that there are no off-by-one cases ?

Comment: If the target value is between `array[mid-1]` and `array[mid]`, then it does not exist in the array... because the array is sorted and there are no intermediate positions.  Yes, I'm absolutely sure that there are no off-by-1 conditions, having done this about a million times.

Comment: Oh, you mean that the probability is 0.999999 then ;-)

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you for the detailed response. I just want something cleared up. This will sound trivial to you but I am trying to understand how you got the new ranges: "Given lo < hi and mid, the two possible new ranges are [lo,mid-1] and [mid,hi]". Right now, trying to understand how to get those ranges and why they are so important. Thank you for your support, appreciate it.

Comment: It's because depending on the test, you either set `hi = mid-1`, which changes the range from `[lo,hi]` to `[lo,mid-1]`, or you set `lo=mid`, which changes the range from `[lo,hi]` to `[mid,hi]`.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you. It makes sense now but just want something understood.
 Without fixing the first problem; that is, without setting hi = mid - 1, is it also possible for me to first prove that lo < mid < hi is true considering mid is rounded down and the fact that lo < hi and then state since lo and hi are set to mid, this does not satisfy lo < mid < hi; hence, this shows that the algorithm doesn't always terminate. Is that also a possible way to prove that the algorithm doesn't always terminate? I can show how I proved lo < mid < hi going from mid-1 < mid <= mid.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Just to clarify what I said. I know you have said to round mid up but this is considering that hi is set to mid-1. I was thinking if there is a way to just use the fact that both lo and hi are set to mid and how that causes the algorithm to not terminate for some cases; hence showing that it doesn't always terminate.

Comment: Yes, that's easy.  Just try the two cases when `hi == lo+1`.  Depending on which way you round, you will get `mid == lo` or `mid == hi`, and then in one of the two cases the range won't change.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Just to clarify something. Why is the fact hi == lo + 1 important here? Why try the two cases when hi == lo + 1?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I think I get why hi == lo + 1 is important. It's because that's when the while loop condition fails right?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Also, this is a different question but related. If mid is rounded down, then it's true that we have mid - 1 < mid <= mid right? I understand why it should be mid-1 < mid because mid is rounded down to the highest possible integer and hence cannot equal mid - 1. But I don't understand how mid can equal mid in the upper bound. As in, why is it not mid - 1 < mid < mid? Thanks again, your help and time is much appreciated.

Comment: At this point, you really need to just try it.  Write down values for lo and hi that differ by one at the start of your loop.  What do you set mid to?  Evaluate both possible results of the >= test.  What do you set lo or hi to?  What are the two possible ranges that will be used for the next iteration?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yeah, thanks for your time and advice. I am going to try and do it myself now and see how it goes. Will post my answer if I get one.

Answer (score 0):

Loop termination proofs can be carried by means of a *variant* function, that can be proven to decrease and to have a lower bound. In the given case, consider the quantity `hi - lo`.

After a single iteration, the new value is one of

- `hi - mid = hi - (hi + lo)//2 = (hi - lo)\\2`
- `mid - lo = (hi + lo)//2 - lo = (hi - lo)//2`

(We used the notation `//` for the by-default quotient and `\\` for by-excess.)

We see that the variant function always decreases, except when `hi - lo = 1` and `lo = mid` is chosen.

---

In general, the variant function can be drawn from the rationale of the algorithm, in which you "do something to get closer to the solution". Here, you reduce the interval of uncertainty. Common problems are off-by-one situations, as is the case here.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just want to get something cleared. Where can I find more info on how "\\" works because I am seeing it for the first time. Also, how do you get to the conclusion that the "variant function always decreases except when hi - lo = 1 and lo = mid"? I can see that it makes sense but I am trying to understand how you came to that conclusion? With what evidence did you come to that conclusion? Thank you for your time and support.